# Difference between Nutch crawl giving depth='N' and crawling in loop N times with depth='1'

Tags: hadoop, nutch

Background of my problem: I am running Nutch1.4 on Hadoop0.20.203. There are series of MapReduce jobs that i am performing on Nutch segments to get final output. But waiting for whole crawl to happen before running mapreduce causes solution to run for longer time. I am now triggering MapReduce jobs on segments as soon as they are dumped. I am running crawl in a loop('N=depth' times ) by giving depth=1.I  am getting some urls getting lost when i crawl with depth 1 in a loop N times vs crawl giving depth N.

Please find below pseudo code:

**Case 1**: Nutch crawl on Hadoop giving depth=3.

// Create the list object to store arguments which we are going to pass to NUTCH

List nutchArgsList = new ArrayList();

nutchArgsList.add("-depth");

nutchArgsList.add(Integer.toString(3));

<...other nutch args...>

ToolRunner.run(nutchConf, new Crawl(), nutchArgsList.toArray(new String[nutchArgsList.size()]));

**Case 2**: Crawling in loop 3 times with depth='1'

for(int depthRun=0;depthRun< 3;depthRun++)
{

// Create the list object to store arguments which we are going to pass to NUTCH

List nutchArgsList = new ArrayList();

nutchArgsList.add("-depth");

nutchArgsList.add(Integer.toString(1)); //**NOTE** i have given depth as 1 here

<...other nutch args...>

ToolRunner.run(nutchConf, new Crawl(), nutchArgsList.toArray(new String[nutchArgsList.size()]));

}

I am getting some urls getting lost(db unfetched) when i crawling in loop as many times as depth.

I have tried this on standalone Nutch where i run with depth 3 vs running 3 times over same urls with depth 1. I have compared the crawldb and urls difference is only 12. But when i do the same on Hadoop using toolrunner i am getting 1000 urls as db_unfetched.

As far i understood till now,Nutch triggers crawl in a loop as many times as depth value. Please suggest.

Also please let me know why difference is huge when i do this on Hadoop using toolrunner vs doing the same on standalone Nutch.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the behavior of the Nutch fetching changes when running stand-alone (straight to hard disk) and integrated with a Hadoop cluster.  The Generator score filtering appears to be much higher with a Hadoop cluster, so the "-topN" setting needs to be adequitely high.

I would suggest running your crawl with a high (at least 1000) "-topN" and not the [default value of 5](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-0.8-dev/bin/nutch_crawl).

This is similar to my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479846/empty-nutch-crawl-list/11660294#11660294).

After doing this, I found that my Nutch crawls on stand-alone and HDFS started to line up better.